# Combining list comprehension and pipe operator

Tags: elixir, list-comprehension

I have a list of quotes as such:

```
[

{"March 28, 2021", "It only took one call for him to help me into a brand new 2021 it was so AMAZINGLY GOOD IM STILL HAPPY love it"},
{"March 28, 2021", "We had been looking for a 2021 Suburban for about 6 months and no one could find exactly what we wanted! We contacted Adrian at McKaig and he told us he could order one for us! Our Suburban was delivered in 4 weeks and had everything on it that we wanted! Adrian, Brandon, Dennis and Freddie all worked with us to get exactly what we wanted! They made phone calls and deals for us right on the spot and we drove out with a beautiful black Suburban! We will definitely use Adrian and McKaig Chevrolet again! Thank you for a fun car buying experience!"},
...
        ]
```

I have been trying to get this function to iterate over each quote in the list to count the number of words in each quote then return the original list with the number mapped to each quote. I'm stuck and don't know what to look for at this point. If anyone can steer me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

here is the code:

```
def count(q) do
  q
  |> String.downcase()
  |> String.replace(~r/@|#|\$|%|&|\^|:|_|!|,/u, " ") 
  |> String.split()
  |> Enum.count()
end

def count_added() do
  items = get_body() #the list of quotes
  Enum.each(items, &count/1)
  for x <- items do 
    Map.put_new_lazy(items, "count", &count/1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Simply calling `Enum.each(items, &count/1)` won't update `items` because of immutability. If you want `items` to become the result of said call, you need to reassign it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Map` in the first place, so call to `Map.put_new_lazy/3` won’t succeed in any case.

Also, it makes a little sense to downcase the string before counting words. What you actually want, would be to split by one or more non-alpha-numeric symbols with [`String.split/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3).

```elixir
input = [
  {"March 28, 2021", "It only took"},
  {"March 28, 2021", "We had been looking for a 2021 Suburban!"}
]

for {title, x} <- input do
  %{title: title,
    text: x,
    count: x |> String.split(~r/[^\p{L}\d]+/u, trim: true) |> Enum.count()
  }
end
#⇒ [
#   %{count: 3, text: "It only took", title: "March 28, 2021"},
#   %{
#     count: 8,
#     text: "We had been looking for a 2021 Suburban!",
#     title: "March 28, 2021"
#   } 
# ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Aleksei Matiushkin! Just one last clarification question. How did you get the value in the `text` key to eliminate the `title` or date in this case?

Comment: I did not understand the question, sorry. In comprehension, I pattern match the input so that `title` becomes the first element of tuple and `x` the second one. The map is built by hand.

Comment: Oh sorry I understand what you were doing now. Thanks so much for your help!